# How to call stored procedures from mvc3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, stored-procedures

I'm trying to use mvc3. The online documentation says how to connect one class to one table. anybody have a suggestion on how to run stored procedures and return the results to a view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MVC is not responsible for the way you access your data. There are many technologies that you can use including

- Plain old ADO.NET
- LINQ to SQL
- NHibernate
- Entity Framework

Comment: Thanks. Can you point me to any example on how to call a stored procedure from mvc?

Comment: You probably want to look into the repository pattern as a way to bridge MVC to your database. And... like I said, the actual technology to call the stored procedure is nothing to do with MVC. See list above and chose the one that suits you best.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ to SQL is probably the easiest way to get it working without any prior knowledge.  Check out Scott Gu's post http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/16/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures.aspx

Comment: THIS IS EXACTLY WHAT I HAVE BEEN LOOKING FOR! THANK! YOU!