# Retrieving Data From Database using Stored Procedure in ASP.NET MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, stored-procedures

How to retrieve data from a database using stored procedure in ASP.NET MVC 4?

Comment: Are you using Entity framework?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18012330/retreiving-data-from-sql-server-2008-to-asp-net-mvc-4-either-by-using-stored-pro

Comment: You can use raw ADO.NET, or you can use Entity Framework - the **data access** is no different in ASP.NET MVC4 than in any other .NET application - establish a connection to the database, execute your stored procedure, get back the results. ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to ColinMckay in [his post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6078285/how-to-call-stored-procedures-from-mvc3)

MVC is not responsible for the way you access your data. There are many technologies that you can use including

```
 1. Plain old ADO.NET
 2. LINQ to SQL
 3. NHibernate 
 4. Entity Framework
```